# Chosen JQuery MultiSelect not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, jquery-chosen

I have a ASP.Net 4.5 website(using bootstrap too) in which I'm using Chosen Multiselect. The multiselect is inside update panel and is working as expected in IE. However the same is not visible properly in Chrome. The control width is not there and hence it is kind of collapsed in the UI. I have attached the screen shot and marked in Red and Green Arrow. [image]

Issue in  - > Web Page with choosen and update Panel.

I have another page in the same website where I dont have a updatede panel and the choosen looks good in both IE as well as Chrome.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanksin advance.

Comment: did you try to set width to chosen like `$('select').chosen({ width: '100%' });`?

Comment: I have tried that already but not working !!

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? F12

Comment: I do not see any error om teh comsole Zed. Would this be because of update panels ? or any CSS ? IE is working without any issues.

Comment: Are you sure your select does have options? Try to move it outside updatepanel and see if it works there. Also, try to let it inside update panel and remove chosen plugin to see if your select does works in there.

Comment: i tried moving outside update panels and it is the same. I have values which is getting bound to the select. In IE i could select multiple values and display already selected values in case of Edit mode. I have two choosen selects one for add mode and one for edit mode. Both are working fine in IE. Any hint would be really helpful.

Comment: Just identified that it is working fine in IE 9. However in IE 10 and Chrome this is not working. I have a gridview and OnRowCommand I'm opening a popup window via asyncpostback trigger !! Any idea ?